# Php cli. zend_mm_heap corrupted

Tags: консоль, php, yii

Привет всем! 
Есть консольное приложение, написанное с использованием фреймворка Yii. ПРиложение при запуске подклчюается к серверу gearman, слушает от него задания, в случае появления задач, выполняет их. Во время выполнения задач сервер может использовать подключения по ssh используя библиотеку libssh2 для php.

В общем, пока эти программы на девелоперской машине писались и отлаживались, они работали идеально, но когда Я перенес их на продакшновый хостинг, попытался там выполнить одно из консольных приложений, меня ожидало фиаско. Интерпретатор ругнулся: **zend_mm_heap corrupted**, и ни ответа, ни привета. В общем, беглый гугль ответа на вопрос, Как эту проблему победить не дал, проблема эта плавающего характера.

Посоветовали выполнить скрипт с установленной переменной окружения USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0, но [этот листинг](http://pastebin.com/djFwNvPL) оказался для меня не информативным. [Листинг strace](http://pastebin.com/CvcKypCW) можете еще посмотреть

ps:// Кто нибудь знает, как сделать бектрейс пхп скрипта, запущенного в консоли? :(

версия пхп на продакшне:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.4-1+debphp.org~precise+1 (cli) (built: Sep 27 2013 11:36:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

ОС на продакшне: Ubuntu server 12.04

версия пхп на деве:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 (cli) (built: Jul 15 2013 18:23:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

ОС на деве: kubuntu 13.04

Comment: gdb, и надо поставить все -debug которые оно попросит

Comment: вообще проблема может быть в каком нить екстеншене, у меня например это был Xhprof, вообще в вашем случае может хватит и strace, но если выпадает неожиданно, то надо включить core dumping подождать падения, и обработать этот дамп с пом-ю gdb, работы на пару часов в сумме.

Comment: @eicto, можете привести ссылок на вменяемый мануал, как правильно консольное приложение сбектрейсить? Я никогда такого не делал, и для меня это проблема.

По поводу проблемы в экстеншне. Я устанавливал php не из родного убунтового репозитория, а из пользовательского репозитория, в котором более новая версия php. Может быть в том репозитории php просто "не до компилилось"? 

Лог strace могу выложить.

Comment: ну у вас же там fatal error вроде как ? просто читайте мануал по gdb, он будет говорить что хочет debug для разных библиотек, установите ему. лог strace покажите, запустите как

    strace -f cmd &>out.txt

Comment: В том то и дело, что никаких Fatal Error. Сделаю, strace сделаю, Как только доберусь до сервера.

Comment: @eicto, strace по ссылке: http://pastebin.com/CvcKypCW